# How can I access a Web server in a VM from an iPad?

Tags: virtual-machine, webserver, remote-access, ipad, connectify

I have a virtual machine (running Windows Server 2012, if it's relevant), on VMware Workstation.

It is running an Apache Tomcat web server, and I'm wanting to access that webserver from an iPad.

Is this feasible, or even possible ?

I have tried running Connectify Hotspot on the host machine, but that only gets me as far as being able to access a webpage on the host machine. It doesn't look to pass the connection through to the VM as they are on different subnets.

Any thoughts are gratefully received.

Comment: Nick, my knowledge on iPad is very limited, I just heared this name. What type of connectivity it uses? WiFi?

Comment: The iPad is using WiFi, though based on that, could use either the Internet or the WiFi hotspot available using Connectify.

Comment: And your workstation also has WiFi, or wired with WiFi AP or router, right?

Comment: The workstation has WiFi too, yes.

Comment: Generally, yes, though not always. However, the issue I think is that the host can see the web server on the VM, and the iPad can see a webpage on the host, but the ipad cannot see the web pages on the VM.

Comment: Yes, they are both on 10.64.244.n  where n is either 122 or 82 on a 255.255.255.128 subnet, which I think puts them on the same subnet

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to give the VM exclusive access to a USB wireless card. Then you could establish a connection to another router where the iPad is connected.

You could also use a remote access software like teamviewer or vnc, although that would give full access to the guest desktop, not safari browser access to the material being hosted (which I assume is what you want).

Basically, you need to either make the web server accessible over the internet, or you need you setup a 2nd network interface that will be on the same subnet as the iPad.

If you're willing to place the web server on the same subnet as everything else, that's the easiest. Just configure vmware to use bridged networking instead of NAT.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is possible. I do all development in VMs and have dozens running on servers. You want to bridge the network. The VM will get its own DHCP address or you can give it a static IP address. Then it behaves just like another station in the network, and it does not matter if you use an iPad or a browser-enabled toaster.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I had a wifi router configured to dish out 192.168.x.x 255.255.255.0 type IP addresses, and could see all the hosts.

I had a web application that was using Tomcat 7 on a Windows 2008 R2 Server. I had a Win7 client and an iphone5 that I wanted to demonstrate being able to log into the web service... but it refused to connect.

I thought I'd turned off all the firewalls for the interfaces, but... on my system I was running the firewall still on the  Domain Controller. So, I had to go that extra step and disable the Firewall protecting the Domain Service.

Then everything worked as it should.